# High-poly normal map wrapping unevenly onto low-poly mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, image, texture-baking

I am having a problem wrapping my high-poly normal map onto my low-poly mesh. It seems that the coordinates of my normal map are not correct or distorted. I baked them exactly on top of each other, set UV as my mapping coordinates, and did all the necessary procedures for baking a high to low-poly normal map. On the left is my high-poly mesh and on the right is my low-poly mesh. What is causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: try to recalculate normals : in edit mode, select all and Ctrl+N

Comment: it could just be that you have the normal map set to 'Color' in the node editor.  Once it's baked, you should change the node to 'Non-Color Data'.  If that does not fix this, you can try uploading the model to PasteAll.org and paste the URL here.